# How to join two tables on distinct values of a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

```
SELECT table1.*
    ,address
    ,job
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.name = table1.name
```

The above query returns result for duplicate values of `name` too. How can I convert the query to get only one value for distinct values of `name` column?

I am using SQL Server

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: provide sample data and your expected output in table format

Comment: You could use SELECT DISTINCT, but since you are selecting all fields from table1, you will not get one row for each name. You should return only a subset of meaningful fields. Provide more information about the structure of the data you are working with.

Comment: @Fahmi  I've added some dummy data which i'm using to test the query

Comment: @NicolaLepetit yes, I'm not getting one row by distinct. But that's what I want. I've added some screen shots of the data I'm using to get desired result

Comment: Why is Nihan|cat not in the result? Because you only want one Nihan result row? But then, what makes you decide for dog over cat? What rule do you want to apply here to pick the desired row?

Comment: @ThorstenKettnerI just want any value related to Nihan. Dog or cat doesn't matter. But if it is required to make the query then you can take the value with minimum 'id'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily accomplish this with `row_number` window function. See query below:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t1.pets, t2.address, t2.job
from (
    select *,
           row_number() over (partition by [name] order by id) rn 
    from Table1
) t1 
join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where t1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a lateral join -- `apply` -- for this purpose:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.address, t2.job
FROM table2 t2 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT t1.*
      FROM table1 t1
      WHERE t2.name = t1.name
     ) t1;
```

Normally, the subquery would have an `ORDER BY` to specify the ordering.  Otherwise the result is indeterminate.

This is often faster than using window functions for this purpose.